# python 2.6 exceptions.TypeError: unbound method _init_() ESMTP client instance

Tags: python, python-2.6, buildbot

I am a completely new user to Python and BuildBot. Currently I am using an e-mail alert 
when the BuildBot build status changes (moves from success to fail, or vice versa), and failing will e-mail every time there is a failed build. I am encountering the following Python error when sending an email is attempted.

```
--- <exception caught here> ---
**ESMTPClient.__init__(self, secret, contextFactory, *args, **kw)
exceptions.TypeError?: unbound method init() must be called with ESMTPClient 
instance as first argument (got ESMTPSender instance instead)**
```

I have found some examples of this error online when searching for an answer, including

> You just need to pass 'self' as an argument to 'Thread.init' and
>   calling the super class

but I am still unsure why there is an error. I would appreciate any guidance/help on why this error has occurred and how to go about resolving the issue. I am not the author of this code so I am unsure of what to be looking for to solve the problem.

The email was working before the following code was changed from gmail account to company account.

```
          c['status'].append(mail.MailNotifier(
                 fromaddr="load.builder@company.co.uk",
                 extraRecipients=["example@company.com",
                      ],
                 sendToInterestedUsers=False,
                 mode=('change', 'failing'),
                 relayhost="smtp.company.lan",
                 useTls=True,
                 smtpUser="lbuilder",
                 smtpPassword="password"))
```

Here's the block of code producing the exception:

```
class ESMTPSender(SenderMixin, ESMTPClient): 
    requireAuthentication = True 
    requireTransportSecurity = True 
    def __init__(self, username, secret, contextFactory=None, *args, **kw):  
        self.heloFallback = 0 
        self.username = username 

        if contextFactory is None: 
             contextFactory = self._getContextFactory() 

        ESMTPClient.__init__(self, secret, contextFactory, *args, **kw) 
        self._registerAuthenticators()
```

SSA

Comment: Can you post the code where this exception is thrown?

Comment: I updated your question with the code that produces the exception (check to make sure I got the indentation correct).  As it stands, I don't know why this code would produce that exception as it looks like ESMTPSender inherits from ESMPTClient.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would be a difficult exception to come by -- Generally you don't call `__init__` explicitly unless you're inheriting from some other class.  Here's one situation where you could get that error:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
       print("In Foo, args:",args,type(self))

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        Foo.__init__(self,*args)  #Doesn't work.  Complains that the object isn't the right type.
```

To fix this, we can make `Bar` inherit from `Foo`:

```
class Bar(Foo):
         #^ Bar now inherits from Foo
    def __init__(self,*args):
        Foo.__init__(self,*args) #This will work now since a Bar instance is a Foo instance
```

If it doesn't make sense to have `Bar` subclassed from `Foo`, you can factor the common code out into a separate function:

```
def common_code(instance,*args):
    print("Common code: args",args,type(instance))

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        common_code(self,*args)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        common_code(self,*args)
```

Although this kind of problem can be difficult to diagnose without actually seeing the code which produces the error.

Comment: Thank you- This is the line which throws the exception:ESMTPClient.__init__(self, secret, contextFactory, *args, **kw)

Comment: from the function: class ESMTPSender(SenderMixin, ESMTPClient):

    requireAuthentication = True
    requireTransportSecurity = True

    def __init__(self, username, secret, contextFactory=None, *args, **kw):
        self.heloFallback = 0
        self.username = username

        if contextFactory is None:
            contextFactory = self._getContextFactory()

        ESMTPClient.__init__(self, secret, contextFactory, *args, **kw)

        self._registerAuthenticators()